# How can I compile QT 4 dlls with msvc 2019?

Tags: qt

I have an old project using QT 4.6.2 that runs on VS 2008. I was able to compile it in VS 2019 with msvc 2019 toolchain but it crashes in run time. I see that the problem happens because when I use the QString::toStdString() function, it involves QTCore4.dll using msvc90.dll (VS2008), but when destroying the std::string the app uses msvc2019. This mismatch ends in the app crash.

I want to fix it by recompiling QTCore4.dll using the msvc 2019 but have no idea how to do this. I got the dll by installing QT and have no instructions how to recompile it.

Is it even possible or is it closed source?
I assume upgrading to QT 5 is also an option but I would like to stay with QT 4 for now.

Comment: I recommend getting the Qt-4.8.7 source code which is here; [https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.7/](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.7/) in either the .zip or .tar.gz install Active State Perl and Python before you configure from a Visual Studio 2019 command prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt 5 is largely source compatible with Qt 4. I would first highly recommend trying to compile your project (and fixing any small issues) against Qt 5.
If you need the Qt Declarative module, you can compile it against Qt 5 if you must.

---

That being said, Qt is released under the Open Source LGPL license.

You can fetch the Qt 4 source code from github: https://github.com/qt/qt

Building Qt 4 involves having perl installed and running configure followed by nmake (for Visual Studio). You will [need to set up some new things](https://forum.qt.io/topic/91623/building-qt-4-8-7-with-visual-studio-2017/4) for Visual Studio 2019, and potentially fix code incompatibilities that the 2019 version compiler digs up.